# collapsing solenoid magnetic field limiter

Tags: emc, emi-filtering

solenoid= 4 ohms , control power= 12-15VDC , NO switch is limited to 3-4 amps or what i call as limit ability . this miniature switch is my concern of welding contacts on release .

Thank you for your advise advise

Comment: Flyback diode, snubber circuit ...

Answer (score 1):

15 volts across 4 ohms is a solenoid current of 3.75 amps. When the contact that controls the solenoid opens an arc will form with a current of 3.75 amps. If your contact is rated at 100 volts when switching coils you need a snubber that can handle the current of 3.75 amps without producing more than 100 volts so this is a resistor of 26.6 ohms. You can connect it across the coil via a normally reverse biased diode that has a peak rating of at least 5 amps and you should be OK.

Comment: Andy , thank you !  The switch does have a 125VAC 6 amp rating and the 3-4 amps VDC.